# What is the tense/modality of these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, tenses, slang, aspect

1. He be like “I know a spot” and then drag you through miles and miles of forest to show you a tiny meadow.
   From Reddit
2. Tora be getting impatient. * wink*
   From top comments on Webtoon

I know this is not proper English. And the first one looks like they just left out 'would' but what about sentence 2? I am very big into how English is actually used by people in everyday life. And it was apparently not a mistake by whoever left the comment. I come from a language that doesn't express tenses through verb conjugations. So I'd like to look into what aspect,tense,or mood 'be getting' conveys here and why similar uninflected phrases like 'be like', 'be V-ing' have been gaining traction over the recent years. Thanks!

Comment: This is [African-American vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) (or somebody trying to imitate AAVE). AAVE has different rules of grammar, but if you just steal expressions from it (like many people do) you will use them wrong.

Comment: Right. As for the tense/modality, these are both examples of [Habitual _be_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be), a construction present in AAVE, but not in whitebread American English.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are a lot of posts that suggest specific subgroups of English speakers are the only users of this sentence structure. In fact many people do speak this way in casual conversation where I grew up in the South of the US. The use of “be” here is actually closest to the Spanish verb “estar.” This verb tense communicates a non-permanent state of being.

So In the first sentence, everything that comes after “be” is indicating an action that is typical of the way “he” behaves. It is not just saying he “is doing that” right now. There is some implied characteristic of that person, greater than the actual action taken.

“Be getting” can be translated to “becoming” in the second sentence.

An easier example, might be something like these sentences:

He be crazy. He be saying stuff like I’m super rich and I’m this and that. We all know he broke AF.

In this example, the first sentence, gives the state of being. The second simply clarifies further the state of being, ie what type of crazy. It is less important that certain actions were taken.

Hope that helps.